# case_when to assign different vector elements to the same column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have multiple dataframes with a simple example below. I want to create one final dataframe that includes different "type"s in one column.

```
df <- data.frame("name" = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))

df2 <- data.frame("name" = c("A", "C"),
                  "type2" = c("type1x", "type2x"))
df3 <- data.frame("name" = c("D", "E"),
                  "type3" = c("type10x", "type20x"))
```

I tried to use case_when() to use "names" for matching;

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(type = case_when(name %in% df2$name ~ df2$type2,
                          name %in% df3$name ~ df3$type3))
```

but getting an error;

"Error in `mutate()`:
i In argument: `type = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! Can't recycle `..1 (left)` (size 5) to match `..1 (right)` (size 2)."

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using two `left_join`s and `coalesce` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

df |> 
  left_join(df2, by = "name") |> 
  left_join(df3, by = "name") |> 
  mutate(type = coalesce(type2, type3), .keep = "unused")
#>   name    type
#> 1    A  type1x
#> 2    B    <NA>
#> 3    C  type2x
#> 4    D type10x
#> 5    E type20x
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much